# Website Development - Binding Website To Different Port

Tags: nginx, web-development-server

So this question is probably stupid because I'm overthinking it, but I just can't help but feel it's wrong. I've got Nginx setup on my server with a website it's pointed to, ports are open both on the machine and the router etc.

Problem I have is I don't want to have the default port open on 80 or 443 really, lets say for example I want 8080 and 8443, if this is my main serving website, then do I need to change the ports I have within Nginx or do I need to change my Cloudflare settings so that the website comes up for people without needing to have [www.mydomain.com:8080](http://www.mydomain.com:8080) for example.

How would I get 8080 to display as if it was the default port 80 basically.

Nginx file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    listen       [::]:8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/domainname;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/domainname;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/domainname;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

I think this is done within Cloudflare like 70% certain, but what would this even be called? Is this a proxy?

Sorry for the simple questions, I'm just looking to learn. :)
~Blood

I tried the above and I need to insert the port at the end of my domain to get it to load.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your website to be served without a port number (so the default ports `80`/`443`) then you need these ports open on the maschine that takes the request so it can process it. If you don't want these ports opened on your maschine, you need another maschine with these ports open that will handle the request. This maschine can then handle the request by forwarding it to somewhere else, like your maschine on port `8080`/`8443`. In that case this maschine is called a proxy, because it intermediates the request and forwards it to another server/application. Then you can listen on your server for requests on those ports and serve them with the files you want.

So if you want your website to be accessible on the default ports but you don't want to open them, then you need another server with these ports open, that can pass the request to your server at the needed port - cloudflare proxy would be one possibility to solve that.

Be aware that the proxy sends the requests itself, so for the application behind the proxy, all the requests look like the proxy itself sent them. Normally a proxy adds additional headers to the request, like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For so the application has a way to know the IP address of the original request (like for spaming purpose etc.).

Let me know if that helps or you got further questions.